# Add elements into a sorted array in ascending order

Tags: python

I have the following program which implements a sorted bag. It adds elements
successfully in sorted order (ascending order) when giving a list.
When I created a new sorted bag with the argument of another bag, it's not in sorted order (instead in descending order). See below

Thanks for the help

```
# Array Class
#----------------------------------------------------
class Array(object):        # Represents an array.
DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 5
def __init__ (self, capacity, fillValue = None):
'''Capacity = static size of array. fillValue is placed at each element'''
    self._items = list()
    self._capacity = capacity
    self._logicalSize = 0
    self._fillValue = fillValue
    for count in range(capacity):
        self._items.append(fillValue)

def __getitem__(self, index): return self._items[index]

def __setitem__(self, index, newItem):      
    self._items[index] = newItem

# ArraySortedBag Class
#----------------------------------------------------
class ArraySortedBag(object):
'''An array-based bag implementation'''
def __init__(self, sourceCollection = None):
    '''Sets the initial state of self, which includes the contents
    of sourceCollection, if it's present'''
    self._items = Array(10)
    self._size  = 0
    if sourceCollection:
        for item in sourceCollection:
            self.add(item)

def __len__(self): return self._size

def __iter__(self):
    cursor = 0
    while cursor < len(self):
        yield self._items[cursor]
        cursor += 1

def add(self, item):
    '''Adds item to self.'''        
    insertIndex = 0

    # First found the index where the item will be inserted at
    for i in range(self._size):
        if self._items[i] > item:
            insertIndex = i
            break
    # Then, shift items down by one position until the insertIndex,
    for i in range (self._size, insertIndex, -1):
        self._items[i] = self._items[i-1]

    # Last, assign value to _items[insertIndex]
    self._items[insertIndex] = item
    self._size += 1

# Test Driver
#----------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
b1 = ArraySortedBag([2000, 2, 1000])
print ("Display bag b1")
for i in b1:              # <------ Correct order, ascending order
    print (i)

b2 = ArraySortedBag(b1)
print ("\nDisplay bag b2")
for i in b2:                 # <----- Wrong order, descending order
    print (i)
```

Comment: Please fix the indenting of the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the second instantiation of class ArraySortedBag, you are passing a sorted list.  The ArraySortedBag.**init**() method adds the items using the add() method.  When add() is called the ***item*** to be added is never less than the existing list.  Therefore *insertIndex* remains equal to zero.  Therefore the new item is added to the beginning of the list.

```
# First found the index where the item will be inserted at
for i in range(self._size):
    if self._items[i] > item:     # item is never less than self._items[i]
        insertIndex = i
        break
```

Comment: Why is the item to-be-added always less than the existing list?

Comment: If so, how to fix the code, so that adding elements would result in ascending order?  Thanks --

Comment: While adding presorted items, each item added will be greater that any already added to the internal list.

Comment: My statement was wrong but I think the conclusion holds.  I will edit my response in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks xxyzzy for pointing out my bug in add() method. Thanks Martineau for clarifications. Thanks all others for helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

For adding items into a sorted list so that one maintains the list sorted, I recommend using the [bisect library's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) insort_left or insort_right.

```
import bisect

list = [10, 20, 30]

bisect.insort(list, 25)
bisect.insort(list, 15)

print list
```